# put_time into stream weird behavior

Tags: c++, stream, c++14

It was my understanding that overloaded operators are translated by the compiler into method calls, for example :

```
stream << "test";
```

Is the same as:

```
stream.operator<<("test");
```

If that is indeed the case, then why does this lead into a compilation error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
   std::ostream s {std::cout.rdbuf()};
   auto t = std::time(nullptr);
   auto tm = *std::localtime(&t);
   s.operator<<(std::put_time(&tm, "%H:%M:%S"));//doesn't work
   return 0;
}
```

While changing the `doesn't work` line to:

```
s << std::put_time(&tm, "%H:%M:%S");
```

Makes the code compile.

Both GCC and MSVC 2017 on C++14 seem to produce an error. Is this a compiler bug or are those two statements not equal?

Comment: Most of the streaming overloads are implemented as global 2-argument overloads, rather than 1-argument member overloads. This allows external programmers to add new overloads without having access to the internals of stream classes. When you call an explicit operator overload you have to select from one of the two forms, and you picked the wrong one, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your code, but reduced:

```
struct X { friend void operator+(X, X); };

int main() {
  X var;
  var + var; // ok
  var.operator+(var); // fail
}
```

The thing is, by explicitly calling the `operator<<`, you are relying on the fact that it is indeed an operator of the class (like `T& T::operator<<(const U&);`) and not an operator defined outside the class (because if the operator is not a member, you can't write `var.operator<<(/*...*/)`).

If you write `var << something`, then in addition to the operators defined in the class, lookup (called ADL) finds the operators defined outside of the class as well.

The operator can be defined outside of the class, because `std::put_time`'s return type is specified to ([[ext.manip]](http://eel.is/c++draft/input.output#ext.manip-10):

> An object of unspecified type such that if `out` is an object of type `basic_­ostream<charT, traits>` then the expression `out << put_­time(tmb, fmt)` behaves as if it called `f(out, tmb, fmt)`, where the function `f` is defined as: [...]

Because the requirement is of the form `var << var2`, nothing prohibits standard library implementations to define it outside of the class so that it is found using ADL.

Comment: Right. I thought adl would kick in for direct calls too, thank you.